# Async/Await + Promisify Problems

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, javascript

EDITED: Console Output:

```
admin.html:43 Metamask logged into successfully
admin.html:280 The Contract is [object Object]
admin.html:281 Everything's ship shape! Contract instantiated asynchronously!
admin.html:336 The inputted value is 0x59A09D00EB11caa5FA70484bF4d78015D10938Bc
admin.html:320 Inside the isItYours method
admin.html:290 getFounder method
admin.html:303 just before whoIsFounder
```

Sorry if this is an amateurish question, or betrays a lack of understanding, but I've been working on a frontend for a project of mine, and I've run into an issue. I've been using Async/Await to get my (HTML + Javascript) frontend to wait until my callbacks to a Contract are finished, so that they can be used with various pieces of my frontend. However, when I tried to use the same or very similar code with my newest page, and I got an error:

```
Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter.
```

This message is only supposed to show up when you use synchronous methods with Metamask, so I was understandably kinda miffed to see it show up in an async function. Here is the complete text of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <label for="contractManager">Contract Manager</label>
    <select id="Contracts">
    </select>
    <div class="container">
    <label for="codeInput" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Enter Your Address (For Now, only working with Test Contract - in future, will be able to enter the Contract's ID too)</label>
    <input id="codeInput">
    <button id="checkContract">Prove that you own this contract</button>
    <div id="hidden">

    </div>

<script>
const promisify = (inner) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        inner((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(res);
            }
        })
    );
//so, this promise ought to return err if the async call returned an error, return res otherwise
     if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
            console.log("Metamask logged into successfully");
        } else {
            console.log("Metamask NOT logged into successfully");
            // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/rxskoaj8487I8J426Zid"));
            //note that I don't intend for this part to actually be used - if you're not logged into Metamask, things are pretty bad and we shouldn't go ahead. This is merely to prevent crashing.
        }   

        //now we need the ABI for RegionalContract2
                 web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
      var RegionalContract2 = web3.eth.contract(
    [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "desc",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "addProposal",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "voterID",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "proposal",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "castVote",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "region",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "contractAddress",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getListFromMain",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "setOver",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "areYouInList",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getFounder",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "key",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getProposalName",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "key",
                "type": "uint8"
            }
        ],
        "name": "getProposalVotes",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "id",
                "type": "address"
            }
        ],
        "name": "haveYouVotedAlready",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "howManyProposals",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "isItOver",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "showWhiteList",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "address[]"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "tallyVotes",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]);

var yourAddress;
var isThisContractYours;
var whoIsFounder;

try{
var RegionalContract2 = RegionalContract2.at("0x2C7a8bACc5757d63669baE4a5457F6aE8F6d49ef", function (error, res){
if(!error) {
console.log("The Contract is " + RegionalContract2)
console.log("Everything's ship shape! Contract instantiated asynchronously!")}
});
}catch (err) {
console.log(err);
}

$("#checkContract").click(function() {

async function getFounder() { //use try/catch to avoid error
    console.log("getFounder method");
        try{

        console.log("just before whoIsFounder");

         whoIsFounder = await promisify(RegionalContract2.getFounder);//this is the problem...but it looks just like a bunch of method already in use in the earlier voterScreens, etc. Hmm. Could it be some issue I already solved in an earlier page, and am now having to re-solve?
          //for some weird reason, async/await doesn't appear to be working for this method. As a result, I've gone back to the old fashioned (function(error, result){ if(!error) }) style of Callback.
        }catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        }

            console.log("This Election's Founder is : " + whoIsFounder);

        return whoIsFounder;


    }

async function isItYours(inputAddress){
   try{
    console.log("Inside the isItYours method");
    founder = await getFounder();
        console.log("founder is " + founder);//also, I 
      if (founder != null){
            if (founder === inputAddress) {//if the Founder is the same as the value entered
                //for now we'll stick with popping up an alert. In final version, should un-hide a piece of the screen
            alert("You are in fact the owner of this Election.");
            }
            else {
            alert("You are NOT the owner of this Election.");
            }
      }
     }catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
     }
}
console.log("The inputted value is " + codeInput.value);
isItYours(codeInput.value);

})
</script>
```

Again, I apologise if this is some sort of obvious newbie question, but code very similar to the one you see above was used in my earlier pages, and it worked (and still does work) just fine there, so I'm not sure what exactly the problem is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

You should be passing a function to `promisify`, not the result of the function. So this:

```
await promisify(RegionalContract2.getFounder())
```

should be this:

```
await promisify(RegionalContract2.getFounder)
```

Comment: You might also consider switching to web3.js 1.0.0-beta, which uses promises.

Comment: Thanks. That stopped the previous error from coming up, at least. However, it now seems that nothing's happening - the code simply stops, and my console suggests that it's getting to the function call, then hanging forever. Do I need to give it more time, or is this one of those problems to do with not attaching a user or an expected account to this transaction? That happened to me before in an earlier part of the project. Please forgive my ignorance, I haven't touched this project in something like two months.

Comment: Could you share your current code? In the code you shared, it doesn't look like either of your `async` functions are even being called.

Comment: It's fairly bulky code, and I don't think it'll fit into a comment. Should I link you to a Pastebin or something?

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: You might also consider moving this off the Ethereum Stack Exchange, since this is almost certainly unrelated to Ethereum. (I think the issue is more about learning how `Promise`s and `async`/`await` work in JavaScript, which is better suited for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Post edited. Yes, I will also repost this to Stack Overflow. Thank you for your time, I really would like to get this out of my hair.

Comment: Your new code seems to use `promisify` on an the `async` function `getFounder`. This won't work, because `getFounder` doesn't accept or invoke a callback. This line: `await promisify(getFounder);` should just be `await getFounder()`.

Comment: I've made the appropriate change, but things seem to be more or less the same. Code's still hanging, and I'm almost certain that 'whoIsFounder = await promisify(RegionalContract2.getFounder);' is the place where it's hanging.

Comment: The code in the post still looks wrong. Could you update it and share the output?

Comment: The post has now been edited.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include console output. This has now been rectified.

Comment: Thanks. Very strange; I can't spot anything else wrong. Try just doing `RegionalContract2.getFounder(console.log)` somewhere to make sure that function works?

Comment: Apologies for the late response, I had to go to bed. I've since retweaked the code ever so slightly, and to my surprise it seemed to work this time!  It seems like I needed to use 'await promisify(RegionalContract2.getFounder)' in getFounder(), then 'await getFounder()' in the isItYours method. 

Thanks for all your help!